# Why same values differ with float and double

Tags: c#

Consider this program

```
float a = 0.7f;

if (a < 0.7)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Less");
}
```

The output is `Less`. Why??

Comment: take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c?rq=1

Comment: the explanation is Very Long. you should read: for basic explanation:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/what-is-the-difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-c?rq=1 for full explanation:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Probably because the binary floating point representation cannot exactly represent a decimal number like 0.7

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes though. Would not have considered it a bad question. Just a duplicate...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `0.7` does not have an exact representation as a `float` or a `double`: it is not an exact sum of negative powers of 2.

It happens that the closest representation of `0.7` as a is `float` approximately `0.69999998807907104492`, while the closest `double` representation is `0.69999999999999995559`. As you can see, `double` is slightly greater, which explains the behavior of your program.

Here is a small demo that you could run to see the values on your system:

```
printf("%20.20f %20.20f\n", 0.7, (float)0.7);
```

([live demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/7IBU7E)).

The takeaway lesson here is that you should not expect `double` and `float` representations of mathematically equal numbers to compare for equality correctly. Only a small subset of fractional numbers are representable in floating point system as exact numbers.

Since the overwhelming majority of fractions would be approximated, it is a good idea to do the comparisons with some level of tolerance. For example, instead of writing `if (a == 0.7)` you should write `if (abs(a - 0.7) < 1E-8)`

Answer (score 6):

You're unknowingly comparing apples and potatoes in your code.

```
float a = 0.7f; // "0.7f" is a float
if(a< 0 .7)     // "0.7" is a double
{
    Console.WriteLine("Less"); //You'll see it because of different representations
}
```

Your check will work as you expect if you match the number types:

```
float a = 0.7f;
if(a < 0.7f)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Less"); // You won't see this
}
```

**This** is why numbers should never be hard-coded. Best way to fix your code:

```
float check = 0.7f;
float a = 0.7f;
if(a < check)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Less"); // You won't see this either
}
```